# Multiplication issue: dividing and multiplying by the same decimal does not return original number

Tags: ruby, floating-point, precision

I am aware of the Floating Point precision issues on multiple languages, but I thought I was only going to encounter those issues when multiplying very small or big numbers.

This simple math is incorrect

```
(byebug) 30*36.3/36.3
30.000000000000004
```

Why is this happening and what is the suggested way around it? I don't want to have to use the `.to_i` function since not always I will be dealing with integers, but I'm okay to rounding the result to up to 2 decimals.

Comment: umm not really, how?

Comment: If you don't want to use `Integer` use `Rational` or `BigDecimal`. `36.3` isn't exactly the decimal number 36.3 since only an approximation of it can be represented by `Float` but with a rational number (`Rational(36.3)` or `36.3r`) you can represent 36.3 as 363 tenths for example.

Comment: `30*36.3/36.3).round(2) #=> 30.0`. See [Float#round](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Float.html#method-i-round).

Comment: The fact that this result is a problem suggests you are using floating-point arithmetic in a way it is not designed for. By and large, floating-point is good for approximating continuous functions. A feature of continuous functions is that “small” changes in inputs have “small” changes in outputs, so little errors in arithmetic operations do not matter much. They are not great for discontinuous functions, where a small change in input can cross a point where the function makes a jump, causing a big change…

Comment: … So the fact that getting 30.000000000000004 instead of 30 is a problem suggests you are doing to do something floating-point arithmetic is not primarily designed for. Which means the problem is not in the floating-point arithmetic (it is working as designed) but in your use. What are you doing that needs a result of exactly 30 instead of 30.000000000000004?

Answer (score 1):

Well your sample of the problem does not cover even smallest part of the issue.

Depending on number of bits used to represent float number following operation

```
n = 1/3
```

n will be represented as 0.333333333333..... if you multiply it by 3 it never be 1 but 0.99999999999.....

For your sample you could use `puts 30*(36.3/36.3)` to get exact result.

Probably you already aware that operation with float numbers is more compute intensive that operation with integer numbers.

Otherwise if you would like to preserve precision then you have to use two part numbers -- numerator (top) and denominator (bottom) both integer numbers.

Create the object which will store numerator and denominator.

In such case 36.3 will be represented as 363 and 10

Now operate as you would operate on fractions (using integer numbers what make calculation much faster)

```
30.0 => 300, 10
36.3 => 363, 10

30.0*36.3/36.3 = 300/10*363/363*10/10
          = nominator(300*363*10)/denominator(10*363*10)
          = nominator(1089000)/denominator(36300)
          = Fraction.new(1089000,36300)
```

To simplify such calculations in future, create class *Fraction* and define methods for operators *,/,+,-,**,=.

```
a = Fraction.new(363,10)
b = Fraction.new(300,10)
c = Fraction.new(0,0)

c = a/b
```

Comment: Hmm... have a look at [Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Rational.html)

Comment: @steenslag Well [Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Rational.html) does what I have described. But for educational purpose OP still could practice coding how to implement something similar -- experience will be invaluable. OP will learn what is _class_, how to overload _operators_, how to implement programming interface. Yes, it will take some time but obtained knowledge will last for the rest of OP's life.

Comment: @steenslan NOTE: in about half an hour I've implemented about half operations provided by [Rational](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Rational.html) -- it was quite interesting to extend my programming experience into _Ruby_ territory.